# Scala syntactic sugar with java listener pattern

Tags: java, scala, listener, pojo

I have to use java code in my scala project. The java code encourages the usage of a listener pattern. The code is something like this:

```
 asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.ning.com/ ").execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>(){

    @Override
    public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception{
        // Do something with the Response
        // ...
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onThrowable(Throwable t){
        // Something wrong happened.
    }
});
```

I am wondering if it is possible to use anything better in scala with this code. I know there is a paper written by Martin Odersky saying that observer pattern is bad but I didn't go deep with the matter.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the signature of your `execute` method, you could write a convenience method to simplify creation of the callback:

```
def async(f: Response => Response)(handler: Throwable => Unit) =
   new AsyncCompletionHandler[Response]() {
      @throws(classOf[Exception])
      override def onCompleted(response: Response): Response = 
         f(response)

      override def onThrowable(t: Throwable) = handler(t)
   }
```

Then you can write your code like

```
 asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.ning.com/ ").execute(async {
    response => // do something with response
 } { 
    caught => // handle failure
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.actors.Futures.future
def asyncDiv(n: Int, d: Int) = future { try { Left(n / d) } catch { case ex => Right(ex) } }
```

Example:

```
scala> asyncDiv(5, 2)
res9: scala.actors.Future[Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.Throwable]] = <function0>

scala> res9()
res10: Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.Throwable] = Left(2)

scala> asyncDiv(3, 0)
res11: scala.actors.Future[Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.Throwable]] = <function0>

scala> res11()
res12: Product with Serializable with Either[Int,java.lang.Throwable] = Right(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

Comment: Is it idiomatic scala to write that all out on the same line? Or is it just for compactness since it's so short and simple?

Comment: This seems very interesting. I will go deep on the topic. Honestly I don't know so well the Left case class.

Comment: Ok after reading http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Either.html now I am following you. But this code could not be mixed with a java listener pattern right? Thanks

Comment: @Matroska I thought you wanted an alternative. If you are bound to that interface, then this won't help you indeed.

Comment: @Ken It is idiomatic to keep short expressions on the same line. Since `try`/`catch` is an expression in Scala, and this is short, then it's usually put on the same line. Another alternative that has been gaining support recently with `if`/`else` is to keep each alternative on a single line. So `try { ... }` would be on the second line and `catch { ... }` would be on the third with that style.